# Add a new queue to a running process

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

If I am creating two processes, I can create a Queue first and pass it to each of the processes like this:

```
def do_something(q):
    # queue passed as q

qu = multiprocessing.Queue()

p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something, args=(qu, ))
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something, args=(qu, ))

p1.start()
p2.start()
```

Then the processes can communicate with each other using the queue.

How can I add a third process p3 that also needs to communicate with, say p1? I can create a new queue and pass it to p3, but how can I then have p1 know about that queue and use it to communicate with p1? N.B. p1 will communicate with p2 and p3 independently.

Thanks,

Julian

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand now that in order for processes to communicate, they must both be given the Queue at the time the process is started. Attempts to do otherwise produce the message:

"Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance"

i.e. You can't give a new queue to an already running process by any means. This makes sense as the OS needs to link the processes to the queue. Just passing in a new queue would not do this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `Queue`, use a `Manager`.

You could for example create a manager that contains a `dict` where the keys are the pid (or any other unique identifier) of the receiving process and the values are a `list` of messages.

Pass this dictionary to each process and they can then use it to send messages to all other processes by appending to the relevant list. To read messages a process simple accesses the dict item with its own ID and pops messages off the list.